# Can a synagogue exist without a Torah Scroll?

Tags: synagogue, sefer-torah

I met in some literature the term "prayer house" by which is meant a place for tefilah, but without a Scroll. Theoretically, this option is possible when there is no Scroll, but a room for tefillah is necessary.

Does this type of synagogue really exist? Does it have another name?

Comment: Plenty of airports have multi-denominational chapels without a scroll. I once saw an Army base where the "multi-purpose room" could be switched to whatever worship was needed that day; for a Jewish service, it had an empty Aron. Rabbi Moshe Feinstein actually wrote about a synagogue in a neighborhood full of vandals where it wasn't safe to leave the sefer Torah in the synagogue ...

Comment: It used to be quite common to keep the community's scrolls in a separate room. There's a whole slew of laws about how and when the transfer is supposed to take place

Comment: It's not common but it is perfectly valid as a synagogue. The problem is you'd always have to go somewhere else on days with a Torah reading.